# Removing data after decimal in Python

Tags: python

I have columns of parsed hex values  from an Excel file

```
4.0
123.0
FFE
5432535.0
```

and the list goes on. I'm writing all the data in this formatted C header file and do NOT want any of the data to the right of the decimal or the decimal itself.

For example:

```
4.0 -> 4
5432535.0 -> 5432535
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

My problem is they are hex val ,so they can contain letters as well. The data is being parsed using XLRD and stored in the variable in this type of format.

```
cell_val3 = sheet.cell_value(row_iteration, 20)
```

Comment: Did you try `split('.')`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by hex values here. Is 123.0 in your example a decimal value (one hundred and twenty three)  or a hex value (0x123) which just happens to have no digits A-F? Do you want to convert the hex values to decimal, or the decimal to hex?

Comment: pseudo hex. I'm appending 0X to the val in a loop. It's used by a c header file, so the actual value is irrelevant since it's physically being written to a file. I fixed my issue with split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reassign the string to the first element after splitting by periods: `s = s.split('.')[0]`

Comment: You don't need the ternary `if..else` - just do `i = i.split('.')[0]`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Oh, yes. If the period is not there, `split` will return the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Say this is stored in the variable `number`. I would do

```
number = str(number)
number = number[:number.index('.')]
number = int(number)
```

This performs a slice of the variable starting from the first position and ending on the character it finds before the '.'; you may have to make the input a String first, depending on how you're reading the data in.

Comment: weird....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 45, in <module>
    cell_val3 = cell_val3[:cell_val3.index('.')]
ValueError: substring not found

Comment: There's nothing weird about it - it tried to find the index of an element that wasn't present. Not every line in your example input contains a `.`.

Comment: Ah, of course. What check can I add to implement the split only if the period is present within the string.  Would something like if number[:number.index('.')] in number then do something work?

Comment: You could try `if '.' in number`, but @Malik's answer is easier.

Comment: The split is actually better, I agree. I've only done a lot of string manipulations in Python, haven't messed with it much further than that.